# ER Diagram flaws

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, erd

I have the following ER Diagram for a bank database - customers may have several accounts, accounts may be held jointly by several customers, and each customer is associated with an account set and accounts are members of one or more account sets.  What design rules are violated?  What modifications should be made and why?

So far, a few flaws I'm not sure about are:

1) Redundant owner-address attribute in AcctSets Entity.

2) This ER does not include accounts with multiple owners with different addresses.

My Question is: How would I go about fixing these flaws and/or other flaws that I may be missing from my analysis?  Thanks!

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: _"accoutns may be help jointly"_ - you mean "held"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the AccountSet entity does.

You have a many to many relationship with Customers and Accounts.  Therefore, you need a CustomerAccount entity that ties a customer to one or more accounts, and an account to one or more customers.

```
CustomerAccount
---------------
CustomerAccountKey
CustomerKey
AccountKey
```

This entity would be accessed by either the CustomerKey, to get the accounts for a customer, or the AccountKey, to get the customers for an account.  The CustomerAccountKey is only used to cluster the data on a database.

The CustomerKey - AccountKey combination in the CustomerAccount entity is unique.

If you want more than one address for a customer, that that becomes a one to many relationship between the Customer entity and the Address entity.  This allows customers to have a summer address and a winter address, as one real life example.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't states a reason for having the abstraction `Account Sets`.  You need an intersection between `Customer` and `Account`, since your business rules say many to many, but why have an intervening abstraction?

Even assuming you keep it, the attribute `owner address` doesn't belong on the abstraction/intersection entity between `Account` and `Customer` (i.e. `Account Set`). That just doesn't make sense.  There is nothing in your stated rules nor in common experience to suggest that customer address has any functional dependency on the relationship between an account and a customer.  If anything, it would be functionally dependent on the customer alone.  As it stands, you are modelling this dependency to be multi-valued, so the address isn't even fully functionally dependent on the customer.  The only 3NF place to put it would be on the `Addresses` entity type.

You should consider a better name than `Addresses`.  First, your entities should be named for the object they represent.  Resist the urge to use plural nouns.  The entity type is not a collection.  The table that implements the entity type will be a collection of your entity instances, but that goes without saying and plural noun naming will just lead you into confusion when you are thinking about cardinalities of relationships.  I'd suggest `Location` as an entity type name, with `address` as an attribute.  When you go beyond the conceptual level `address` is almost certainly going to have to be decomposed.

Other than that, you are on a pretty good track, based on the business rules you've cited.